# when I try to end an event controlled loop in c it takes two inputs?

Tags: c

When I run it and try ending the loop I have to enter -1 twice.
Does anyone know why?
I'm a beginner so I don't really know what's wrong with the code.
I need to know what's wrong cause the compiler doesn't tell me the problem
I'm using Codeblocks.
This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int grilled_duck = 1; /*initializing grilled duck to 1 portion*/
    int salad = 3; /*initializing salad to 3 portions*/
    int rice = 4;  /*initializing rice to 4 portions*/
    int soup = 2; /*initializing soup to 2 portions*/
    int order; /*initializing order variable*/

    /*printing the menu on the screen and giving codes to every meal*/
    printf("  the menu:\n");
    printf("  %d portions of grilled duck (order code = 1).\n", grilled_duck);
    printf("  %d portions of salad (order code = 2).\n", salad);
    printf("  %d portions of rice (order code = 3).\n", rice);
    printf("  %d portions of soup (order code = 4).\n", soup);

    /*taking the orders from the user input using an event controlled loop
and decreasing the meals portion*/
    printf("  what would you like to order (to finish your order enter -1).\n");

    while(order!=-1)
    {
        scanf(" %d\n", &order);
        order=order;
        if(order==1 && grilled_duck!=0)
        {
            grilled_duck=grilled_duck-1;
            printf("what else?\n");
        }
        else if(order==2 && salad!=0)
        {
            salad=salad-1;
            printf("what else?\n");
        }
        else if(order==3 && rice!=0)
        {
            rice=rice-1;
            printf("what else?\n");
        }
        else if (order==4 && soup!=0)
        {
            soup=soup-1;
            printf("what else?\n");
        }
        else if(order==-1)
        {
            printf("thanks for ordering, your meal will be ready soon.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("sorry we have any, anything else?\n");
        }
    }

    /*after taking the user orders the program print the updated menu*/
    printf("\n  the updated menu:\n");
    printf("  %d portions of grilled duck.\n", grilled_duck);
    printf("  %d portions of salad.\n", salad);
    printf("  %d portions of rice.\n", rice);
    printf("  %d portions of soup.\n", soup);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `order=order`...em, what? rather, why?

Comment: `int order; /*initializing order variable*/` that's absolutely wrong!!

Comment: `/*initializing order variable*/ `, no here you are _declaring_ that variable. But remove that comment anyway, it's superfluous, like having this kind of comment: `foo = bar;  // assign bar to foo`

Comment: thanks I well correct these but what about the mean problem?

Comment: @ahmed11037 Exercise for you: Eliminate the multiple calls `printf("what else?\n");`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I think I should put
`printf(what else?\n); `
at the end of the loop

Comment: @ahmed11037 you're on the right path.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this statement: `order=order;` is nonsense and should be removed

Comment: @user3629249 okey I removed it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
scanf(" %d\n", &order);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &order);
```

The trailing whitespace character (`\n`) in format specifier means it ignores any number of whitespace after scanning an `int`. You don't need any whitespace character at all in scanf here because `%d` already ignores any left over whitespace characters.

Also note `order` is not initialized during the first iteration. Using `do {..} while(..);` loop is probably better suited.

Also see: [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
scanf(" %d\n", &order);
```

The format string contains a newline after the `%d`.  This causes the newline you enter after inputting a number to be consumed.  As a result, `scanf` is still waiting on input before it returned.

Remove the trailing newline after `%d` (as well as the leading space).  This will allow pressing ENTER to terminate the `scanf` call.

```
scanf("%d", &order);
```